# Gitlab CI: do not trigger pipeline when commit done by certain user

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have an automated process that commits a status file at the end of every merge request. We would like to configure a pipeline that runs on every commit except for commits by this user. Currently the pipeline is configured like so:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make test
  except:
    changes:
      - "the_status_file"
```

However, sometimes the status file doesn't change at all. In that case, the pipeline runs.

Instead, we would like to configure the pipeline to ignore commits by a certain user (this user being the automated one we created). Is this possible in gitlab ci?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of such feature in Gitlab CI. However if your user is a script creating and pushing commits and you have control over it, you could decide whether to trigger the CI pipeline or not by inserting (or not) `[ci skip]` or `[skip ci]` in your commit message.

See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#skip-a-pipeline

Comment: As of today, ``[skip ci]`` still works, but the sub-anchor in the documentation link no longer exists, and there's no reference to ``[ci skip]`` or ``[skip ci]`` on that page.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I changed the URL (the "Skip a pipeline" section has been moved to the "CI/CD pipelines" page.

Answer (score 3):

That could be done with [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rules)

```yaml
rules:
    - if: '$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN == "username"'
      when: never
    - when: on_success
```

Comment: The hard part is, I don't think this bot has a username. We tried this with the email as well, and for some reason it didn't seem to work